# Select Query throwing Invalid number error

Tags: mysql, oracle

Hello first time using Oracle SQL Developer and I'm trying to do a select join on two tables and I get the error "ORA-01722: invalid number". What is causing this error?

All of the Google results point to creates/inserts that are invalid.

Here is my query, both CUSTNO and ARCUSTO_ID are of type NUMBER(15,0)

```
SELECT 
    ARCUSTO.COMPANY, SHIP_TO.ADDR1
FROM 
    ARCUSTO 
INNER JOIN 
    SHIP_TO ON ARCUSTO.CUSTNO = SHIP_TO.ARCUSTO_ID;
```

Comment: It sounds like one of the fields doesn't have a numeric type (in ARCUSTO.CUSTNO = SHIP_TO.ARCUSTO_ID)

Comment: Unless one of the two tables is a view that is doing some sort of data type conversion, or you have something else in your query that is doing data type conversion, I'm hard-pressed to believe that both `custno` and `arcusto_id` are numeric columns.  I'd wager that one or the other is a `VARCHAR2` that is supposed to contain numeric data.

Comment: **both CUSTNO and ARCUSTO_ID are of type NUMBER(15,0)** prove that please. show us `CREATE TABLE` statements and/or create sqlfiddle. By the way even if type is NUMBER, could value be NULL in Oracle?

Comment: Run `select distinct 'ARCUSTO' tbl, DECODE( TRANSLATE(CustNo,'0123456789',' '), NULL, 'number','contains char') isNumeric
from Arcusto UNION select distinct 'Ship_to' tbl, DECODE( TRANSLATE(ARCUSTO_ID,'0123456789',' '), NULL, 'number','contains char') isNumeric
from Ship_to` if you get more than 2 records, or one of them results in 'Contains char' your data types are not numeric.  (post results)  The engine isn't going to lie to you.  If it says invalid number, then one of the fields contains data that isn't numeric or contains decimal or something...

Comment: Thanks for all the help, after double checking it turns out it was user error...sigh.... CUSTNO is `CHAR(10 BYTE)` my mistake